# Change date format in Sharepoint template

Tags: sharepoint, date

Using SharePoint 2007, I downloaded Microsoft's Employee's Training Scheduling and Materials template from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B5206277-550C-44DA-A2D5-D7E32E3B6B8F

This is exactly what I wanted but the date format for Start/End date is in the format "MM/dd/yyyy" (US). I want it in "dd/MM/yyyy" (UK) but cannot for the life of me find where I can change this simple detail. Any advice?

EDIT: I have found the offending piece of code:

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="EventDate" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@EventDate')}"/>
```

But I can't seem to see how the date would be formatted. The exact same piece of code is used elsewhere (different id and a pre-installed template) and displays the date correctly.

EDIT: OK Still having problems with this. When I Edit Items the dates are formatted correctly, but when it is displaying the dates they are displayed incorrectly. Any ideas?

Correct:
[image]

Incorrect:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you edit that offending piece of code then add a `LocaleId="2057"` if @Ryans solution does not work for you.  I had the similar situation before and adding that worked for me

ie

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" LocaleId="2057" ControlMode="New" FieldName="EventDate" __designer:bind=" ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@EventDate')}"/>
```

Comment: This is it...nearly. It wasn't in the `FormField` that I needed the `LocaleId` but in the XSL. I changed `ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@EventDate), 1033, 5)` to `ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@EventDate), 2057, 5)`. Cheers for that. I'll give you the bounty when it allows me in 7 hours!

Answer (score 2):

Generally the date format is defined by the site regional settings and not hard coded into any template.

Have you checked Site Actions > Site Settings > **Regional Settings** > Locale ?

Comment: Yeah that worked! I don't know why but every other subsite seems to have the correct regional settings, but this one didn't. Cheers. But only for the form field. I am displaying a DataFormWebPart, populated with XSL, and it's fields are still in US format.

Comment: It actually didn't work, it only worked for Edit Fields and not display fields. :(

Answer (score 0):

I consider you want to display list items with date format.
You can create a Custom Display Form. In that add the Custom List Form.
In custom form there comes the option for choosing date.

I think this is helpful.